# Do we need Html Encoding if I am using ValidationRequest=True to prevent from XSS(Cross-site scripting) in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, encoding, xss

I am using ValidationRequest="True" in asp.net and it doesn't allow user to input html tags and scripts but I have been told to do html encoding while displaying user data in browser saying uses of single inverted comma(') and double inverted comma(") could cause XSS scripting.

When I went through various sources, I think encoding is not needed if I am not allowing html and script in page. I am not able to create the situation where we need encoding in backend while we are using validationRequest=true in asp.net page. I really don't want to use html encoding if it is not necessary.

Is there any example where after using ValidationRequest=true and still necessary to do html encoding ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encoding user supplied data is important. You really should encode everything that comes from the user. Even though the user will be blocked from entering anything that looks like a tag (basically anything with an angle bracket) quotes are dangerous in other situations such as being included in an attribute of an html element.

For example, say you have a page with a button that calls a JavaScript function with some data that a user supplies.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Do something"></asp:Button>
```

In your code behind you set the client click attribute to some user supplied value:

```
string userInput = ""; // <-- from wherever
btnSubmit.OnClientClick= "someFunction('" + userInput + "')";
```

If your user inputs something like `a'); location.href = "http://www.evil.com"; //` your submit button is going to do something that you really don't want it to do - navigate somewhere evil.

Although that's clearly a very contrived example, it's generally best to just encode ALL user input.

Comment: Thank you very much .<br/> I tried with  a');alert(document.cookie + ' cookie hacked and I am able to get user cookies. I see the importance of encoding. Is this also mean, if I am not using user data in javascript and just assigning user data in asp.net controls(like lblName.Text = userdata) then don't need to encode user data ? Do I need to encode every user data or just to encode where I feel vulnerable ? Can you please provide me more example in another scenario. I want to share with my colleague to show the importance of encoding.

Comment: In the case of setting a label's text, the supplied value is treated as html it is therefore potentially vulnerable to XSS. Have you heard of OWASP? You may find their take on XSS interesting: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A3-Cross-Site_Scripting_(XSS)